# SQL to 'group' certain records

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by

I am not entirely sure if this is possible in SQL (I am by no means an expert).

I have lines of data in TABLEA like below:

[image]

I wish to have an SQL output that will 'group' any records together that where Activity!=D. The output results would need look like the table below:

[image]

Any 'merged' activities would would be grouped as 'Merged'. In the example, this would be A and B.

I got started

```
select 
  cycle_start,
  cycle_end,
  activity_start,
  activity_end,
  case when (Activity="D") then "D" else "Merged" end
```

but then I struggle to get the aggregation correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a `case` in the `group by`:

```
select cycle_start, cycle_end,
       min(activity_start) as activity_start, 
       max(activity_end) as activity_end, 
       (case when Activity = 'D' then 'D' else 'Merged' end)
from table t
group by cycle_start, cycle_end,
         (case when Activity = 'D' then 'D' else 'Merged' end)
```